# Fuzzy collapse in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, duplicates, levenshtein-distance

I am working on a **deduplication** project in **O(n)** time where i precompute clusterIDs and then collapse the results of elastic query with those IDs. It is working pretty well already, but i found out that by using **Levenshtein distance treshold** between IDs it is working a hundred time better. I was wondering if there is any way to do that in elastic, and if not, if there is any way to ask them to implement the feature ? or if you have any other idea to do that without injuring the query time ?

Comment: I am quite confused about your aim, could you elaborate / give an example ?

Comment: For example, i have document A with id 101001011 and another one (B) with id 101001010, currently they don't collapse with the collapse query because there is one char of difference between them. I'd like to be able to say, with the collapse, that if id of A and id of B is only different by n char, collapse them anyway